# can continuously differentiability deduced from continuous partial differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

If not, what is the sufficient and necessary condition of continuously differentiability? I have searched a lot, but I can not find a detailed reference discussing continuously differentiability.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for a reference, the following theorem in Rudin's *Principle of Mathematical Analysis* should answer your question:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. And tell me the importance of this book.